# Firefox extension preference not recorded in Windows

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, preferences

I'm having a simple preference pane for Firefox Extension as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<prefwindow title="Preferences"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <preferences>
        <preference id="extensions.autofc.signalSuccess" name="extensions.autofc.signalSuccess" type="bool"/>
        <preference id="extensions.autofc.dpair" name="extensions.autofc.dpair" type="string"/>
    </preferences>

    <prefpane label="Preferences"> 
        <checkbox preference="extensions.autofc.signalSuccess" label="Tell me if everything is okay"/> 
        <label value="NOTE: Errors are always alerted"/>  

        <html:hr />
        <hbox align="center">
        <label value="Pair Options" />
        <groupbox>      
        <radiogroup preference="extensions.autofc.dpair">
            <radio label="Pair 1" value="ee"/>
            <radio label="Pair 2" value="ev"/>
        </radiogroup>
        </groupbox>
        </hbox>
    </prefpane>
</prefwindow>
```

This works perfectly on Linux, meaning users can tick or untick the checkbox or select radio buttons, click Okay and when the Preference is opened again, the latest selections are saved.

What amazed me was that when this was tested on Windows, the selections are not saved, i.e., when opening Preference Pane again, the selections return to the default values.

One thing I've supposed was that the selections in this preference Pane are handled by Firefox but I may be wrong.

Do you guys have any insights on why this doesn't work on Windows. In particular, it didn't work on FF 3.6.1, FF 8, FF 7.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: No obvious issues with your code. What if you go to `about:config` and set the values there, do they stay after restarting the browser? Also, please open Error Console - any errors showing up there when you use your pref pane?

Comment: Thanks Wladimir. I think Nikolay's suggestion has worked wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place `<preferences>` inside `<prefpane>`, not `<prefwindow>`.

Comment: It works. So amazing. It's a new lesson learned. Thanks a lot Nikolay!